# redirect to a actionresult in mvc but not want to go to page by return view()

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i want a facility that   if user login then goes to home/index

i not want to use

```
return view('~/views/home/index');
```

i want to redirect it to a actionresult index of home controller of my web-application(in asp.net mvc)

how i can do this without return view(); i want to redirect him.

```
public actionresult login

if(userlogin)
{
// goes to index page ? what i do here then user goes to index page of home controller
}
else
{
return view()
}
```

Comment: BTW, if you created your MVC project using the project template in Visual Studio, it should have already generated the Account controller for you.  Even if you chose not to use it, it would demonstrate things like this that you could use.  (Since Darin's answer is exactly what it does...)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You could redirect:

```
return RedirectToAction("index");
```

and if the action is on a different controller specify the controller name as well:

```
return RedirectToAction("index", "home");
```

Comment: i used   return Redirect("/home/index");

Comment: That's not good as you are hardcoding the route `/home/index` and the day you modify your route rules it will bite you.

Comment: Plus, *return Redirect("/home/index");* fails as soon as you're running in a vroot.  At least preface it with a "~", though doing the *RedirectToAction()*, as Darin pointed out, is much better.